# How to generate new wallet address per token

Tags: bitcoind, address, address-generation

I'm using getnewaddress bitcoin-cli function to generate wallet addresses but i need one address per token.

Is it possible to use a parameter like seed for random numbers to get the same address when i use the same token?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. here is the function to get tone address per token:

```
try:
    addressjson=gateway.getaddressesbylabel(token)
    address=list(addressjson.keys())[0]
except:
    address=gateway.getnewaddress(token)
return address
```

this way if an address assiciated to the label: token exists we use. Otherwise we generate a new address with label token.